# angularjs translate display the value of the key in the chosen language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I have the following data in my i18n translation file:

```
"mylist" : {
    "fruits": [
          {
            "key": "A",
            "value": "Apple"
          },
          {
            "key": "B",
            "value": "Banana"
          }
    ]
}
```

In my markup, I get it like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="user.fruits" name="fruits" theme="selectize">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="f.key as f in transl.mylist.fruits | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="f.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

In my markup I read it like this:

```
<td>{{user.fruits}}</td>
```

So I see the `key` in the output, because I have stored the key in the ng-model, because I have several languages, so I want to store the same key, but display different values for each chosen language.

Now the question is: 
**How can I display back the value of the key in the chosen language?**
so that the `value`is shown instead of the key. How can I look it up back in the translation file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a function to search the selected key in list

```
$scope.displaySelectedValue = function(option) {
 for(var i=0; i <transl.mylist.fruits.length; i++) {
  if(mylist.fruits[i].key === option)
   return mylist.fruits[i].value;
 }
}
```

call that function passing selected fruit value

`<td>{{displaySelectedValue(user.fruits)}}</td>`